# Angular ui-map (google map) residing in html partial and hidden with ng-if does not add markers

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, angular-ui

I hide the map-element initially using ng-if. When the ng-if evaluates to true I cannot add markers to the map. The map-element is contained in a html partial - it is not part of the initial html-page.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MapCtrl">     
   <div style="width:100%;height:300px" ng-if="whatever">       
     <div ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers" ui-map-marker="myMarkers[$index]"
         ui-event="{'map-click': 'openMarkerInfo(marker)'}">
     </div>       
     <div id="map_canvas" ui-map="myMap" class="map"
         ui-event="{'map-click': 'addMarker($event, $params)', 'map-zoom_changed':  'setZoomMessage(myMap.getZoom())' }"
         ui-options="mapOptions">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div style="width:100%;height:300px;background:yellow" ng-click="showMap()">
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('doc.ui-map', ['ui.map','ngRoute'])
        .controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout', function ($scope,$timeout) {



$scope.myMarkers = [];

$scope.mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.784, -78.670),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

$scope.addMarker = function ($event, $params) {
        console.log('addMarker');

        $scope.myMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map: $scope.myMap,
                position: $params[0].latLng
        }));          
};

$scope.setZoomMessage = function (zoom) {
        $scope.zoomMessage = 'You just zoomed to ' + zoom + '!';
        console.log(zoom, 'zoomed');
};

$scope.openMarkerInfo = function (marker) {
        $scope.currentMarker = marker;
        $scope.currentMarkerLat = marker.getPosition().lat();
        $scope.currentMarkerLng = marker.getPosition().lng();
        $scope.myInfoWindow.open($scope.myMap, marker);
};


$scope.showMap = function(){
        $scope.whatever = true;           
}

$scope.setMarkerPosition = function (marker, lat, lng) {
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
};     
}]) ;
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm stuck in the same situation as you - Bootstrap tabs - map displays fine (using the browser resize event hack), but markers won't show up.

Comment: https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/15

Answer (score 1):

The 'ng-if' directive will create or remove a portion of DOM based on expression. The ng-if expression is equal to false when you launch the map app.

So the map-ui element does't append to DOM tree and the 'myMap' property won't be added to the controller scope. This will make addMarker() broken because $scope.myMap === undefined
You could try to add the following code to your addMarker function and it should show undefined on your console:

```
console.log($scope.myMap);
```

Although ng-show caused the wrong map width/height problem, you could enforce map refresh by dispatching "resize" event when initialize the map.

You need to trigger a event "resize" on Google map object when you want to refresh the map.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map,"resize");
```

My Example:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular UI Map</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
    <input type="button" ng-click="showMap()"/>
    <div ng-show="isShow">
        <div id="map_canvas" ui-map="myMap" style="height:200px;width:300px" ui-event="{'map-click':'addMarker($event, $params)'}" ui-options="mapOptions">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-ui-utils/modules/event/event.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-ui-map/src/map.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=onGoogleReady"></script>
  <script src="js/angularUIMap.js"></script>
  <script>
    function onGoogleReady(){
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("map"),['mapApp']);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

angularUIMap.js

```
angular.module("mapApp",['ui.map'])
.controller("mapCtrl",function($scope,$timeout){
  var mapInitFlag = false;
  $scope.showMap = function(){
    $scope.isShow = !$scope.isShow;
    if(!mapInitFlag)
    {
        $timeout(function(){
            google.maps.event.trigger($scope.myMap,'resize');
            mapInitFlag=true;
            console.log('adjust map');
        }); 
    }
  };

  $scope.myMarkers = [];

  $scope.mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.784, -78.670),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  $scope.addMarker = function ($event, $params){
    $scope.myMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.myMap,
            position: $params[0].latLng
    }));          
  };
});
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Hope this helpful.

Comment: Chickenrice - thank you that is very helpful, but only when the map-element exists in the initial html-page. I did not make it clear, but in my case I have the map-element in one of the html-partials. Perhaps this is a too difficult task to try to accomplish? I'm thinking I could perhaps try to put the map-element in the initial html-page. But thats a different controller.=) Any ideas here?

Comment: Could you update your question? I think it can work even use template to append the map element. But I can't find that you load the map in html partial way in this question.

Comment: Question is updated. I will look into templates now.

Comment: so... could you also update the source code for more details?